# numpy : slice an array while looping around borders of array (topology of a donut)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to slice a numpy array by potentially overlapping the borders of the array. I expected to have a topological doughnut in my hands, but this doesn't lead to what I expected to be.
as an example is worth a thousand words :

```py
import numpy as np
# a 10x10 array with c
arr =np.array([[ c + 10 * r for c in range(10)] for r in range(10) ])
print(t[1:3,8:1])
```

gives

```
[]
```

even though I would have expected :

```
[[ 81,82],
 [ 91,92],
 [  1, 2]]
```

I thought that python supported negative position but it fails too when using :

```py
print(t[1:3,-2:1])
```

```
[]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Slices can't do this.  The block isn't contiguous,  Either use advanced indexing, or replicate the array and slice that.  Wrap around topology is not natural to numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

as [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63431639/numpy-slice-an-array-while-looping-around-borders-of-array-topology-of-a-donu?noredirect=1#comment112164907_63431639) mentionned it is not possible.

However, it is possible to use `numpy.append` or  and create a new array storing the custom-slice.
Unfortunately, this would make changing data in the original array by editing data in the slice impossible.

This last limitation makes it impractical and useless for my case, but if you stumble on this question and you don't need the result to be reference, feel free to leave a like.